# C# Quartz.NET misfirepolicy not working (cron expression)

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm working on a Program with Quartz and I have a problem when I resume my job.
If I resume my job it gets fired multiple times. I searched google but the misfire police solution does not work on my side.

This is how I initialize my Job. I use a cron expression (gets fired every 10 seconds) and I also have the Misfire DoNothing Handle.

```
        public static IJobDetail? job;
        public static ITrigger? trigger = null;

        public static JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("InboxCheckJob", "group1");
        public static TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("InboxCheckTrigger", "group1");

        public static async void Init()
        {
            string intervalcron = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inboxCheckCron"];

            Console.WriteLine("InboxCheckInit");
            logger.Info("InboxCheckInit");

            try
            {
                IScheduler scheduler = HelperClass.GetScheduler();
                await scheduler.Start();

                job = JobBuilder.Create<Jobs.InboxCheck>()
                    .WithIdentity(jobKey)
                    .Build();

                trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                    .WithCronSchedule(intervalcron, x => x
                        .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()
                    )
                    .Build();

                await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                logger.Error(ex.ToString()); 
            }
        }
```

I Pause my job like this.

```
        public async Task PauseJob(string id) 
        {
            try
            {
                var scheduler = HelperClass.GetScheduler();

                var jobdata = await HelperClass.JobDetails(id);

                JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobdata.jobname, jobdata.group);
                TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey(jobdata.triggername, jobdata.group);

                if (jobKey != null && triggerKey != null)
                {
                    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("called pause");

                    await scheduler.PauseJob(jobKey);
                    logger.Info("Paused Job: " + jobKey.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And this is how I Resume my Job.

```
        public async Task ResumeJob(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                var scheduler = HelperClass.GetScheduler();

                var jobdata = await HelperClass.JobDetails(id);

                JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobdata.jobname, jobdata.group);
                //TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey(jobdata.triggername, jobdata.group);

                //await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("jobkey: " + jobKey.ToString());

                //var job = await scheduler.GetJobDetail(new JobKey(jobdata.jobname, jobdata.group));
                //var trigger = await scheduler.GetTrigger(new TriggerKey(jobdata.triggername, jobdata.group));

                //await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("job: " + job.ToString());

                if (jobKey != null && triggerKey != null)
                {
                    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("called resume");

                    //await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                    await scheduler.ResumeJob(jobKey);
                    logger.Info("Resume Job: " + jobKey.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is my Log output. So it gets fire at 30 sec. Then it gets fired 6 times.

```
2022-03-28 10:15:30.3223 DEBUG == AUTO == update app_scheduled_task set lastexecute = '28.03.2022 10:15:30', nextexecute = '28.03.2022 10:15:40', lastduration = '00:00:302' where id = 2
2022-03-28 10:15:34.2063 INFO Paused Job: group1.InboxCheckJob
2022-03-28 10:16:34.1687 INFO Resume Job: group1.InboxCheckJob
2022-03-28 10:16:34.5750 DEBUG == AUTO == update app_scheduled_task set lastexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:34', nextexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:44', lastduration = '00:00:393' where id = 2
2022-03-28 10:16:34.5750 DEBUG == AUTO == update app_scheduled_task set lastexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:34', nextexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:44', lastduration = '00:00:394' where id = 2
2022-03-28 10:16:34.5750 DEBUG == AUTO == update app_scheduled_task set lastexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:34', nextexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:44', lastduration = '00:00:391' where id = 2
2022-03-28 10:16:34.5750 DEBUG == AUTO == update app_scheduled_task set lastexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:34', nextexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:44', lastduration = '00:00:391' where id = 2
2022-03-28 10:16:34.5954 DEBUG == AUTO == update app_scheduled_task set lastexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:34', nextexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:44', lastduration = '00:00:405' where id = 2
2022-03-28 10:16:34.6414 DEBUG == AUTO == update app_scheduled_task set lastexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:34', nextexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:44', lastduration = '00:00:457' where id = 2
2022-03-28 10:16:40.3023 DEBUG == AUTO == update app_scheduled_task set lastexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:40', nextexecute = '28.03.2022 10:16:50', lastduration = '00:00:289' where id = 2
```

What is my Problem that the misfirepolicy is not working?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, there is a misfireThreshold config.

I set my Scheduler now like this

```
        public static async void SetScheduler()
        {
            NameValueCollection config = new NameValueCollection();
            config.Add("quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "1000");

            factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(config);
            scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

            Console.WriteLine("Set Scheduler...");
        }
```

The `config.Add("quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "1000");` is set to 60000 in default. Which basically says: If the job is not longer paused than 1 minute it is not considered as a misfire.

I set it to 1 second on my side, now it works.